# How can I get the distinct value inside 2D or any nD array using Python 3?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to get the distinct value(s) inside a 2D or nD array and then print some message when it saw one or more.

```
arr = [[1,1,3],[2,4,2]]

Distinct values inside array: 3, 4

Duplicated values inside array: 1, 2
1 appeared 2 times
2 appeared 2 times
```

I tried this initial code but no luck (incomplete code):

```
import numpy as np

R = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
C = int(input("Enter the number of columns: "))
  
matrix = []
print("Enter the numbers:")

for i in range(R):         
    a =[]
    for j in range(C):     
         a.append(int(input()))
    matrix.append(a)

arr = np.array(matrix).flatten()


def areDistinct(arr) :
    n = len(arr)
    s = set()
    for i in range(0, n):
        s.add(arr[i])
    return (len(s) == len(arr))

 
if (areDistinct(arr)):
    print("DISTINCT")
else :
    print("DUPLICATED")
```

Comment: This is my final code [link](https://onlinegdb.com/ssB42fbwz) . Maybe this is not perfect but this one works me. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try flattening the array and then putting it through the built-in `Counter`

flattened = flatten(arr)
counts_of_values = Counter(flattened)

and then just filter based on the counts, so like this:

```py
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
flattened = list(chain(*arr))
c = Counter(flattened)
distinct = [k for k, v in c.items() if v < 2]
duplicated = [k for k, v in c.items() if v >= 2]
```

Comment: It works! Thanks :) but is there a way to solve this without importing chain and Counter? I mean just plain loop

Comment: Sure there are ways, but built-in functionality is there to be used :)
One such way is going through the list and seeing if the values have been already seen ( another list). With chain you dont need to import it, but using it is one of the best / most idiomatic ways of flattening a nested array in my opinion. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you out :)

Comment: @AleksJ why would you not want to use `Counter`? If this is homework you have to be clear about this in your question.

Comment: @AleksJ please don't request to mark your answer as accepted, this is not mandatory to accept an answer and doing this could be felt as pressure to accept yours ;)

Comment: All of the responses here helps me :) but this one resolve my problem, Thank you!

Comment: Well said, I shouldnt have mentioned accepting the answer @mozway, though I think you marked the wrong person, I wasnt requesting to not use counter :)

Comment: @AleksJ yes my first highlight was incorrect (aimed at bigstep) ;)

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged your question with *Numpy* tag, I suppose that
you are looking for a *Numpythonic* solution (in contrast to
plain Pytnon).

So start with the necessary import:

```
import numpy as np
```

I assume that you created your *arr* something like:

```
arr = np.array([[1,1,3],[2,4,2]])
```

First compute unique values and their respective counts (how many times
each value occurs):

```
vals, cnts = np.unique(arr.flatten(), return_counts=True)
```

The second step is to compute *uniqueness* indicators:

```
uniq = cnts == 1
```

For your data sample the results are:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
array([2, 2, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
array([False, False,  True,  True])
```

Then, to generate your expected printout, run:

```
print(f'Distinct values inside array: {", ".join(map(str, vals[uniq]))}')
print(f'Duplicated values inside array: {", ".join(map(str, vals[~uniq]))}')
for i in [ind for ind, x in enumerate(uniq) if ~x]:
    print(f'{vals[i]} appeared {cnts[i]} times')
```

No need to import any other packages like *collections* or *itertools*.

Comment: Thanks! I'm out of idea that's why I tried to use numpy =D but can you also make it in plain loop or without using any import.

Comment: If you are interested in a plain loop, then look in the other answers. There is no point in repeating their solutions. But in my opinion using *Numpy* is more smart than "ordinary" flattening and looping.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [[1,1,3],[2,4,2]]

res = dict()

# compute histogram
for inner_arr in arr:
    for a in inner_arr:
        if a in res:
            res[a] += 1
        else:
            res[a] = 1

# scan histogram and check for distinct values
for r in res:
    if res[r] == 1:
        print(f"The value {r} appeared once.")
    else:
        print(f"The value {r} appeared {res[r]} times.")
```

you can easily scan res and return all keys that has associated values 1. You can see res dictionary has a histogram.

Comment: Thanks! How can I only check the distinct values? I mean if (distinct): print("there are distinct values inside this array")

Comment: This is not the most compact form you can achieve the same result. I gave you a syntax that explicitely shows the logic of the procedure.

Comment: Thanks! I did used the last part of your code :) **[link](https://onlinegdb.com/9mvlqDnfX)**

Answer (score 0):

```
values=dict()
arr=[[1,1,3,4,6,6,7,4,3,2,5,7],[3,2,1]]
for i in arr:
    for j in i:
        if j in values:
            values[j]+=1
        else:
            values[j]=1
distinct = []
duplicate = dict()
for i in values:
    if values[i] == 1:
        distinct.append(i)
    else:
        duplicate[i] = values[i]
print(distinct)
print(duplicate)
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm receiving an error like values[j] is out of range